# Does onReceive get called in BroadcastReceiver for AlarmManager if device is already awake

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm having trouble getting my BroadcastReceiver to work. The onReceive is not getting called. I am not using a service. I am setting the alarm in my activity's onCreate method. I am also using the RTC_WAKEUP. But what if my device is already awake? Will the onReceive get called anyway? I want the onReceiver called even if the device is awake. Normally I need to have the receiver called even if the device is asleep but I also want to execute the code my receiver carries out when the activity starts manually. Here is how I am starting my alarm:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, ServiceStarter.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),  pi);
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name=".ServiceStarter" android:exported="true"></receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if my device is already awake? Will the onReceive get called anyway?

Yes.

> Here is how I am starting my alarm:

You are using `getActivity()`. The component is not an `Activity`. It is a `BroadcastReceiver`. Use `getBroadcast()` to build a `PendingIntent` that will trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`.

> In the manifest:

Remove `android:process="remote"`, as you do not need it, and it harms the user by wasting RAM. Also, remove `android:exported="true"`, as you do not need it, and it weakens security by allowing anyone to trigger your `BroadcastReceiver`.